# Retrieve mySQL Data Greater Than 2 Months From Todays Date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wanting to extract data from a mySQL database which shows the members with a subscription date which has expired 2 months or more from the current date. i.e. the day I run my PHP report.

I've tried using the query below to pull the data from my database, but it's not extracting any data.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userid, forename, surname, subscriptionexpiration FROM {$table} WHERE subscriptionexpiration BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND now() ORDER BY userid DESC");
```

The date is stored in my database as ddmmyy, so I'm not sure whether this is the issue or whether my query is incorrect.

**Full Script**

```
<?php
$db_host = 'hostname';
$db_user = 'username';
$db_pwd = 'password';

$database = 'databasename';
$table = 'userdetails';
// use the same name as SQL table

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd)) 
die("Can't connect to database"); 

if (!mysql_select_db($database)) 
die("Can't select database"); 


function sql_safe($s)  
{      if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())  
        $s = stripslashes($s);  

    return mysql_real_escape_string($s);  
}  

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  
{  
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))  
    {  
        if (isset($_POST['del'])) 
            $userid = intval($_POST['del']); 

        if (mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE userid={$userid}")) 
            $msg = 'The member who you selected has now been deleted!';  
        else 
            $msg = 'Could not delete the selected member'; 
    } 
}  
?> 
<html><head> 
<title>Members With 2 Month Subscription Expiration</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.style2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.style3 {font-family: Calibri}
.style6 {font-size: 16px}
.style7 {font-family: Calibri; font-size: 16px; }
-->
</style>
</head> 
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="style7">
<?php 
if (isset($msg)) // this is special section for 
// outputing message 
{ 
?></p>
<p class="style7">
  <?=$msg?>
</p>
<?php 
} 
?>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userid, forename, surname, subscriptionexpiration FROM {$table} WHERE subscriptionexpiration > now() and datediff(month, now(), subscriptionexpiration) >= 2 ORDER BY userid DESC");    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty 
echo 'There are currently no members where their "Subscription Date" is greater than two months!'; 
else 
{ 
echo "<table>\n"; 
while(list($userid, $forename, $surname, $subscriptionexpiration) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{ 
echo "<tr>\n" 
."<td><input type='radio' name='del' forename, surname value='{$userid}' /></td>\n" 
."<td><small>{$forename} {$surname}</small><td>\n" 
."<td><small>{$subscriptionexpiration}</small><td>\n" 
."</tr>\n"; 
} 
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">"; 
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete Selected Member" name="submit"/>'; 
echo "</td></tr>"; 
echo '</table>'; 
} 
?> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" /> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution**

```
("SELECT userid, forename, surname, subscriptionexpiration FROM {$table} WHERE subscriptionexpiration <NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH ORDER BY userid DESC");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 'where' clause use [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx). This would look like

```
$result = mysql_query(
      "SELECT userid, forename, surname, subscriptionexpiration 
         FROM {$table}  
         WHERE subscriptionexpiration > now() and  
             datediff(month, now(), subscriptionexpiration) <= -2 ORDER BY userid DESC");
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply. I've tried your code and unfortunately I receive the following error:
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/memberlist7.php on line 77
which in my code is the line directly below the query which is:
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty.
Any ideas please? Kind regards

Comment: Hi, please see my comment at the end of this page. I've been looking at my table structure and realised that this field is set as a varchar rather than a date. I'm not sure whether this may be creating the problem. Kind regards

Comment: Not sure if that is your specific problem but in the datediff (and checking if the subscription date is greater than the current date) you need a date (or smalldatetime). You can change the column or you can cast it as a smalldatetime.

Comment: many thanks for this. I think I need to go and have a look at my table structure and possibly make some changes to the 'Subscription Expiration' field. I'll then have another go, taking into account what you've said. Kind regards

Comment: I went back to change the format of the 'Subscription Expiration' field to a proper date field rather than a VARCHAR, so the format of the field is now YYYY-MM-DD. I've run your suggested query with this change, and unfortunately it's still not retrieving the data. Any ideas please? Kind regards

Comment: Can you give me an example of your data or something.... I feel it would be easier to help you if I have a better idea what you are doing.

Comment: Hi @Kyra. I've added the full script to my original post, so hopefully this will help. Regards

Comment: Hi @Kyra, you should be able to see the script now. Thanks

Comment: Hi @IRHM realized that since the current date is before your expiry date in the datediff the result would be a negative number. So if it is 2 months expired it would be -2 while 4 months expired is -4. So instead of datediff(...) >= 2 it should be datediff(...) <= -2. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I've tried making the change and unfortunately I'm receiving the following error:
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/memberlist5.php on line 77. 
Line 77 is this line in my code: if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // table is empty. Have you any ideas please?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I don't have alot of experience in PHP. Can you run the SQL within the mysql environment and see what your result is. It looks like it doesn't like your argument (ie. your result from the sql)

Comment: Hi, I've run this through mySQL as:
SELECT * FROM `userdetails` WHERE subscriptionexpiration > now() and datediff(month, now(), subscriptionexpiration) <=-2 ORDER BY userid DESC, and it returned the error: '#1305 - FUNCTION db369054642.datediff does not exist'

Comment: Aw shoot. I'm sorry. I just realized that the function I was using is Microsoft SQL and not mysql. I just this up and this site(http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp) uses datediff without the 'month'.

Comment: Hi, that's absolutely no problem, it's all part of the learning process :) I did some more reserach after you posted the link and I found a post from someone with a similar query. I adapted it a little and it works a treat. I've added the solution to my original post. Many thanks for all your time and trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql appears to be backwards.  You are asking for all rows where the subscription expires between 2 months from now and now which you won't find.  It should be between now and 2 months from now.  Always start with the oldest date when using between dateA and dateB

You may need to do some casts on the date field and the between dateA and dateB to get everything to match up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  userid, forename, surname, subscriptionexpiration
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  STR_TO_DATE(subscriptionexpiration, '%d%m%y') BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND NOW()
ORDER BY
  userid DESC
```

Comment: Hi many thanks for taking the time to help me out with this. I've tried the code and although I didn't receive any errors it doesn't retrieve the one record which has an expiration date of 011011 i.e 1st October 2011, so it should show up on the report. Kind regards

Comment: Hi, I've just been looking at my table structure and realised that this field is set as a varchar rather than a date. Could you tell me please would this make any difference? Kind regards

Comment: I think for this field it is better to use DATE type. It will help you to avoid problems with formats. Who knows, is it 'ddmmyy' or 'yymmdd'?

Comment: @Devert, many thanks for your time and trouble. Rather than me taking up more of your time, I'm going to make some changes to my table structure and I'll take it from there. Once again many thnaks and kind regards